# insert all Ascii chars with scanf(%10s)

Tags: c, linux, ascii

This program uses the `scanf` function and `%s` as the format specifier. This function is fix and I can not change anything in the program. Now I have to insert characters so that I get a special ASCII code in the storage. I already found out that if I want to write NUL (0x00) into the storage I can use 'Ctrl'+'Shift'+'@'.

How can I get all the other special ASCII numbers?

I don't know if this is important, I use linux and have an english keyboard.

Comment: It isn't quite clear what you are trying to do. Is your question about typing non-English characters on an English keyboard?

Comment: Dont talk about your code bit show it.

Comment: You cannot. `scanf("%s", ...)` will, by design, ignore whitespace (ENTER (ascii `10`, `13`), SPACE (`32`), TAB (`9`), ...)

Comment: https://fsymbols.com/keyboard/linux/unicode/ <- maybe you're looking for this? It doesn't usually work in the console but you can use it in a text editor and paste from there...

Comment: I try to give more details. The code uses scanf(%10s, foo). The rest of the code is not important because the only thing that I can do is executing the code. I can not change anything.
If I execute the code I can insert a string into scanf. For instance ABC. This values are stored in foo as 0x41 0x42 0x43 0x00. But now I want to insert a string into scanf so that I can store any values in foo. For instance 0x02 0xe7 0x00. Now my problem is that I don't know what I should insert to achieve this.

Comment: @dratenik I looked into it. It seems like they only work with ascii code which has a symbol. But for instance 0x00 is a control and has no real visual representation. But I want to write all possible ascii values into the storage. For instance for 0x00 i can type ctrl+shift+@ to get this value. The visual representation is ^@ but this is only one symbol. So it is not possible to get the same output if I first type ^ and then @.

Comment: Control - letter may get your codes 1 to 26.

Comment: You can send arbitrary data from a shell using something like `printf '\012' | ./a.out`, but there is no way to get scanf to write whitespace or null into `foo` unless you change the conversion specifier.

Comment: @William Pursell - A `scanf` implementation which would not write a NUL from the input stream into `foo` would not conform to the C standard, which demands for `%s` to accept _a sequence of non-white-space characters_, of which NUL is one.

Comment: @Armali True; scanf will write the NUL.  But there is no way for the caller to know it, since it cannot distinguish between a NUL that is read and the one that scanf writes to indicate the end of the data.

Comment: @William Pursell - The caller can fill the array with non-NUL values before and inspect it after the `scanf` call; the last NUL then is _the one that scanf writes_, any other NUL was read.

Comment: @Armali.  What if the content of the buffer after `scanf` is `"012345678\x00\x00"`}  You can't tell if scanf read 10 chars, the last of which was NUL, or if it only read 9.  But this is a purely academic question!   You are correct that `scanf` can write the NUL, but it is completely useless.  You would need to put a `%n` in the format string if you want to do this sort of thing.

Comment: @William Pursell - As I wrote, if I filled **the array with non-NUL values before** **the `scanf` call**, I can tell that every NUL therein except the last one has been read, so in your example 10 characters were read. And I wouldn't call it _useless_ to correct misconceptions.

Comment: The null value is not useless for my case :) And scanf will also continue after reading null. So it is possible to write 123\x0045 into foo.
@chux-Reinstate Monica. How can I access this control letters? I know that the first ascii values are just controls but I don't know how I can write them into scanf.

Comment: Ok, I just found out how I can write them. ctrl+v+(a,b,c,...) (The list for the control keys is on wikipedia ^^)
Now i want to write also \x80 to foo. I checked in an ascii table that this is Ç, so it has a visual representation, but I can not write it. So I thought that I can copy it but if I copy it, I get \xc3\x87 and not \x80. What am I doing wrong? How can I write \x80 into foo?

Comment: @greeny Note: "I checked in an ascii table that this is Ç"   \x80 is not an [ASCII](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII) character. That table you referred may be some variation of  _extended_ ASCII.

Comment: Some keyboards allow <ALT down> <number pad 1> <number pad 2> <number pad 8> <ALT up>  to form character 128.